# Override a <Teleport /> that is defined in an imported package in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, primevue

I am using [PrimeVUE's DataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/datatable/filter) with filtering. I have it set to "menu", which causes a dropdown menu to appear, allowing users to fill in a query which will filter the rows based on that.

Internally, PrimeVUE uses Vue's `<Teleport />` component to attach te menu to `body`. Generally, this is good.

However, in my specific case, I use "Single SPA", which wraps the whole app inside `#single-spa-application:web-app-2`.

All styling is contained inside `#single-spa-application:web-app-2`. So, once I click the "filter" button, no styling is applied to the dropdown menu because it's outside of the CSS scope:

[image: Image showing lack of CSS styling on dropdown menu]

Some other PrimeVUE components provide an `appendTo="#single-spa-application:web-app-2"` option, which works wonderfully. However, this component does not.

**Is it possible to "override" any Teleports within a certain component to point somewhere else?** Currently, the only way I see is to actually fork and modify their code.

Comment: Are you using JSF?

Comment: Sorry @JasperdeVries, I thought PrimeFaces was the name of the "main" product, and PrimeVue was one of the "ports".

Comment: Damn, desperately need a solution for this.